# c++ std::map `emplace` and `emplace_back` overloading

Tags: c++, data-structures, std, stdmap

My problem is the following:

I have a pair of functions:

```
using my_map_t = std::map<int, double>;
using my_map_iterator_t = my_map_t::iterator;
my_map_t my_map;

...

void func1(int a, double b) {
    ...
    my_map.emplace(a, b);
    ...
}

void func2(int a, double b, my_map_iterator_t hint) {
    ...
    my_map.emplace_hint(hint, a, b)
    ...
}
```

I would like to avoid code duplication and to be as fast as possible. One possible solution that I found is the folloqing

```
template <bool has_hint>
func(int a, double b, my_map_iterator_t hint=my_map.end() /*unused if has_hint=false*/) {
    ...
    if constexpr(has_hint) 
        my_map.emplace_hint(hint, a, b);
    else
        my_map.emplace(a, b);
    ...
}
```

But unfortunately I do not have a c++17 compiler on the target machine.

I was thinking about using a default parameter for hint such that `emplace_hint` will have exactly the same effect of `emplace`. However I imagine the map being implemented as a (RB) tree and so the desired iterator would have been computed every (probably as the "median iterator")

Can you suggest me an elegant way out?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `func(int a, double b, my_map_iterator_t hint=my_map.end())`?  You don't really lose anything if the hint is wrong.  It think it's a single extra comparison, maybe a node traversal.

Comment: Well, it is a very performance critical feature and I expect that the most common behavior to be the one without hint.

Comment: Have you actually measured if there is a hit?

Comment: Also, do you need ordered data?  `std::unordered_map<int, double>` theoretically has better performance if you don't need ordering.

Comment: @NathanOliver, there is one comparison more, then there is a useless call to `my_map.end()`. Unfortunately, I need ordered data! However it is a nice suggestion if one does not need so high performances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might factorize with a common method:

```
template <typename F>
void func_impl(int a, double b, F emplacer)
{
// ...
    emplacer(my_map, a, b);
// ...
}

void func1(int a, double b) {
    func_impl(a, b, [](auto& my_map, int a, double b) { my_map.emplace(a, b); });
}

void func2(int a, double b, my_map_iterator_t hint) {
    func_impl(a, b, [&hint](auto& my_map, int a, double b) { my_map.emplace_hint(a, b, hint); });
}
```